# Port iOS Swift app into Xamarin for Windows deployment

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a simple tabbed app coded in Swift using a Storyboard layout. Is this something I could import into Xamarin and then deploy into a windows environment? I couldn't understand the documentation whether it could take existing swift code and port the code or what. Microsoft Bridge does not support Swift yet and I couldn't understand or get RemObjects Silver to work either and would really like to get my app in a Windows environment. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, MS Bridge for now(25.07.2016) supports Obj-C only. And there is no way to port swift app to windows.

Even with Xamarin you can only compile static library in xcode and than make binding to use it from c# ONLY on iOS. You can reuse Storyboards in Xamarin project, but again only on iOS.

As for RemObjects Silver, it brings swift language to other platforms, but unlike Windows Bridge it doesn't map Foundation, UIKit or other iOS frameworks to Windows or android. So you can use only swift syntax calling target platform API.